# How can i change an atributte of an object using hooks in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code and when i click on the button 'Conclude', all atributtes 'complete' of my object array are changing. But i want only set 'complete' of the object that i clicked. Could someone help me?

Inicializing the data state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      nome: 'Tarefa1',
      horarioInicial: '10:00',
      horarioFinal: '17:00',
      status: 'não iniciado',
      id: 1,
      complete: false,
    },

    {
      nome: 'Tarefa2',
      horarioInicial: '10:00',
      horarioFinal: '17:00',
      status: 'não iniciado',
      id: 2,
      complete: false,
    },

    {
      nome: 'Tarefa3',
      horarioInicial: '10:00',
      horarioFinal: '17:00',
      status: 'não iniciado',
      id: 3,
      complete: false,
    },
  ])
```

Function to set data state and rendering the list

```
const completeHandler = () => {
    setData(
      data.map((el) => {
        if (el.id === data[0].id || el.id === data[1].id || el.id === data[2].id) {
          return {
            ...el,
            complete: !el.complete
          }
        }
        return el
      })
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((el, key) => (
        <li key={key}>
          {el.nome} {el.horarioInicial} {el.horarioFinal} {el.status}
          <button className="btn btn-primary">Iniciar </button>
          <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={completeHandler}>
            Conclude{' '}
          </button>
          <button className="btn btn-warning">Pausar </button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way would be to make a separate component out of each `<li></li>`'s so that they only have their own state.
Otherwise you need to pass an identifier to the `completeHandler` callback, here `id` can be used.
You can use a similar strategy by passing an anonymous function or by [binding your callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) with the element id.

```
const completeHandler = (id) => {
    setData(
      data.map((el) => {
        if (el.id === id)
          return {
            ...el,
            complete: !el.complete
          }
        }
        return el
      })
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((el, key) => (
        <li key={key}>
          {el.nome} {el.horarioInicial} {el.horarioFinal} {el.status}
          <button className="btn btn-primary">Iniciar </button>
          <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => completeHandler(el.id)}>
            Conclude{' '}
          </button>
          <button className="btn btn-warning">Pausar </button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
```